# Multiplayer without using Windows Live?

Tags: c#, xna, multiplayer

I'm making a game in XNA and I'd like it to be multiplayer. However, upon putting in the `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices` in my games code, it causes my game to crash. I know this is because of the full XNA Game Studio not being installed.

My question is, is it possible to do multiplayer without LIVE? If so, what are some good alternatives?
I want the game to support at least 16 people doing something together.

Also, I'm not totally against LIVE, if there is a way to install XNA fully on a users computer automatically I would definitely do it. Something like when it installs the XNA redistributable upon starting up for the first time.

Comment: [gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) can probably help with this too.

Comment: You can use peer-to-peer (P2P) mode of WCF.  Only useful if you are targeting Windows desktop